# Can someone explain to me why using pop() on a list equal to self.list also get self.list pop the last place

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to build a game in pygame with OOP and I got into a problem.

The problem is that when I tried to pop the last item from the list, `self.list` got popped as well.

This is a simpler version of the problem:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def pop_equal_list(self):
        list_that_should_get_popped = self.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped
        list_that_should_get_popped.pop()
```

And when you try to run it the outcome is this:

```
Ex = Example()
Ex.pop_equal_list()

print(Ex.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped.__len__())



Output : 4
```

I expect that the length of `self.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped` will be 5 and not 4 meaning I would like it to not pop.

Comment: They are the **same list**. Also, please always tag python questions with the generic [python] tag. As an aside, just use `len`

Comment: pop is an in place operation and both variables refer to the same list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Python a list variable only holds a reference to the list, so when you do:

```
list_that_should_get_popped = self.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped
```

you are only copying the reference to the list that `self.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped` references to the variable `list_that_should_get_popped`.

You should instead assign to `list_that_should_get_popped` with a new list:

```
list_that_should_get_popped = self.list_that_shouldnt_get_popped[:]
```

Comment: stop answering obvious duplicates, you should be using your dupe-hammer to close these questions, there's probably 100 of these a day.